# Can you use “brauchen” for “need to”?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

In English, *need to* and *must* are basically the same thing.  Kann man dafür *brauchen* sagen?  Oder muss man *müssen* benutzen? (Can you say *brauchen*? Or must you use *müssen*?)

> 1) *Ich brauche zu essen.*, oder *Ich muss essen.*
>   2) *Ich brauche ein neues Handy kaufen.*, oder *Ich muss ein neues Handy kaufen.*

Comment: Not sure what I think of mixed language questions. I would prefer a question in only one language. If you attempt German and it is badly phrased, we will do our best to phrase it bettter and correct out errors. I'll ask meta soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can checkout the different meanings of *brauchen* in a dictionary like the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brauchen).

The answer to your question is a clear "yes and no" ;-)

In some cases, you can use *brauchen* to express *need to*. These are cases that contain a restriction or negation, so strictly speaking you can express *don't need to*, *only need to* and the like this way:

> Er braucht heute nicht zu arbeiten. He doesn't need to work today.
>   Du brauchst es mir nur zu sagen. You only need to tell me.

In colloquial speech you can omit the 'zu', because many people forget the old rule

> Wer *brauchen* ohne *zu* gebraucht, braucht *brauchen* überhaupt nicht zu gebrauchen.
>   Whoever uses *brauchen* without *zu* doesn't need to use *brauchen* at all.

Beside these cases, you cannot use brauchen this way. So in your examples it is

> Ich muss (etwas) essen.
>   Ich muss ein neues Handy kaufen.

Also note that

> Ich brauche zu essen.

is correct, but means

> I need food.

Comment: In the last example, there is an implicit indefinite pronoun (_Ich brauche was zu essen_). Also, even people who do know the rule may decide to ignore it and instead watch the birth of a new modal verb. (In related news, the final *t* in third person singular is often dropped, as in _er brauch gar nicht wiederzukommen_, similar to the conjugation of other modal verbs.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, *brauchen* will be used with an accusative object in the meaning of *I need something*.

> Ich brauche Essen.
>   Ich brauche ein Dach über dem Kopf.

This conflicts so strongly with *brauchen*’s other usage meaning *need to* that that usage is restricted to the cases Matthias mentioned: When there is another word at least between *brauchen* and the infinitive.

> Ich brauche Arbeit. (noun)
>   <strike>Ich brauche zu arbeiten.</strike> (doesn’t work)
>   <strike>Ich brauche heute zu arbeiten.</strike> (at the very least extremely uncommon if not wrong)
>   Ich brauche nur heute zu arbeiten. (works; only today, not tomorrow)
>   Ich brauche nicht zu arbeiten. (works)

---

Normalerweise gebraucht man *brauchen* mit einem Akkusativobjekt in der Bedeutung *benötigen*.

> Ich brauche Essen.
>   Ich brauche ein Dach über dem Kopf.

Das beißt sich so sehr mit dem anderen Gebrauch von *brauchen* in der Bedeutung *müssen*, dass dessen Verwendung auf die Fälle, die Matthias erwähnt hat, beschränkt ist: Wenn mindestens ein weiteres Wort zwischen *brauchen* und dem Infinitiv steht.

> Ich brauche Arbeit. (noun)
>   <strike>Ich brauche zu arbeiten.</strike> (doesn’t work)
>   <strike>Ich brauche heute zu arbeiten.</strike> (at the very least extremely uncommon if not wrong)
>   Ich brauche nur heute zu arbeiten. (works; only today, not tomorrow)
>   Ich brauche nicht zu arbeiten. (works)

Comment: Zweisprachige Antwort, weil die Frage sich nicht auf eine Sprache beschränkt // bilingual answer becaues the question doesn’t use only one language.